# How to find out which IP and Port is JIRA() method accessing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, jira

I am using the following script to get issues from Jira.

```
from jira import JIRA

options = {'server': 'https://it.company.com/'}
jira = JIRA(options, basic_auth=('user', 'password'), max_retries=1)
issues = jira.search_issues('project="Web"', startAt=0, maxResults=50)
```

I want to replace `https://it.company.com/` with `https://ip:port`.

I used`ping` to get the `IP`.
I used `nmap` for checking ports, but no matter what `https://ip:port` input I use, I can't get a connection. I also tried these [ports](https://confluence.atlassian.com/kb/ports-used-by-atlassian-applications-960136309.html).

How can I find out which `IP` and `Port` is `JIRA()` accessing?

Comment: Are you able to reach `https://ip:port` using a web browser?

Comment: Since it's HTTP, the answer to this is irrelevant - server may respond to `http://company.com:80` but not to `http://10.0.0.10:80`.

Comment: @rtx13 If I just type the ip I reach Confluence page, but with the ports nothing opens. I can't access jira with any

Comment: Can you access jira using `http://ip/` or `https://ip/`?

Comment: @rtx13 nope, just the confluence page. I can then switch to jira from the confluence page, but then the url changes too

Comment: Did you try using that URL in your python code?

Comment: @rtx13 also, `https://ip` cannot be accessed, just the `http://ip`. That url is just `https://it.company.com`

Comment: I'm a little confused. It sounds like `https://it.company.com/` works fine in a web browser, but the identical URL does not work in your python script?  Is the web browser you're accessing the URL from, and the python script, running on the same host/PC?

Comment: ... did you try `http://it.company.com` in your python script?

Comment: @rtx13 there is a misunderstanding, `https://it.company.com/` works fine in the script, I just want to know what's the corresponding `ip:port` of it

Comment: Ah, that would be 443, the standard port for `https`.

Comment: @rtx13 that was the first thing I tried :D, but the script doesn't run with it. Also the website is not accessible with `ip:443`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210743/discussion-between-rtx13-and-snow).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the script works and you just want to know how the connection looks, I recommend letting it run and in the background execute `netstat -ano`.

If the script doesn't work and you just want to know where it tries to connect, I recommend installing `wireshark`.

Edit: In any case you (most likely) won't be able to replace it with `ip:port` because servers treat HTTP requests to an IP different than how they treat requests to a name.

Comment: the script works yes. i will try your commands and let you know

Comment: where should I be looking for the python process in `netstat -ano`?

Comment: The left-most column is the process ID. The command `tasklist /fi "imagename eq python*"` will show all running processes.

Answer (score 2):

The `https` protocol uses port 443.  Refer to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS#Difference_from_HTTP) for details.

However accessing a server via `https://server_name/` is different from accessing a server via `https://server_ip_address/`.  This is because during TLS negotiation, `server_name` is passed to the server via TLS SNI (Server Name Indication).  This way multiple virtual websites may be hosted at the same `server_ip_address`.  See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Ask the Jira admin to tell you. Configured in conf/server.xml like any Tomcat app, or there may be a remote proxy such as nginx configured in front of the Jira